# Recover changes lost in a deleted git branch

Tags: git

I was given a set of changes.  Made the changes, tested locally, **thought** I committed and pushed those changes (this was yesterday).  Designer asked me about them today, I checked, they were not showing on production, nor were they showing on my working machine.  The branch had already been deleted.

I'm a git newbie, so after some searching I discovered `get reflog` and was able to find the commit that has all of the changes, and checkout a new branch based on this.  When I checkout the branch, I see the changes on the web site, when I switch back to master branch, the changes are gone - exactly what I would expect.

Now, I can't get those changes to merge into master; when I try to merge, git says that it's already up-to-date.

To illustrate, I've included some screen shots:

With my 'uhoh' branch:

[image]

And the master branch:

[image]

Again, while on branch master, running `git merge uhoh` it responds with "Already Up-To-Date".  There is clearly a difference, I just don't know how to get it from uhoh to master.

Comment: Maybe uhoh has already been merged into master, but later commits undid some of the changes made in uhoh? Try running `git log --oneline --graph --decorate master uhoh` and you should be able to see whether or not that's the case.

Comment: That wasn't the case, but I love the output your command gave me, it's going to be very useful in the future I'm sure. And, had I had it prior to doing all the cherry-picking, it would have made it more clear which ones I needed to focus on.

Comment: Glad you found it useful. If you find yourself using that command a lot (like I do) you can create an alias for it: `git config --global alias.lg "log --oneline --graph --decorate"`. Then it's just `git lg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
git cherry-pick SHA1-of-commit
```

?

You can run `cherry-pick` while being on master, it will fetch the specific commit and apply it to the current branch. More info [@ manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html)

Comment: This worked perfectly for getting all those changes in.  Had I seen Ajedi32's comment prior to cherry picking, it would have been easier to see the SHA's for all commits I made during that branch. Thanks!